# Wrap first/last 2 posts in different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, blogger, feed

I am trying to create a similar featured section like on [this site](http://dicedandspiced.com/). The script that I'm using is the one below but the problem is that I have just one item variable and I'm not able to add posts on the left/right side of the middle one since all the posts are wrapped the same. How can I style each post separately? I want to wrap the first and last 2 posts in a div container so that I can put the large one in the middle.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function mycallback(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
          var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
          break;
        }
      }
      var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var postAuthor = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
      var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
      var entryShort = postSummary.substring(0,400);
      var entryEnd = entryShort.lastIndexOf(" ");
      var postContent = entryShort.substring(0, entryEnd) + '...';
      var postImage = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url.replace('s72-c/','s1600/');
      var item = '<div class="wrapper"><img src="' + postImage + '"/><h3><a href=' + postUrl + '>' + postTitle + '</h3></a><span>'+ postAuthor + '</span><p>' + postContent + '</p></div>';
      document.write(item);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?orderby=published&max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you be able to post the output html? The appropriate fix for this is proper html layout and css;

```
.image:first-of-type{
 width:40px;
}

.image:last-of-type{
 width:40px;
}
```

They're called Pseudo Classes. You could find more about them here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: Hi Jerdine, The html is stored in the item variable. I want to be able to wrap the first two/last two posts in a different div container like on that site. I don't think this can be done using only CSS because I want to display the first/last two posts on top of each other while the third one stays in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery so you can try this 
, Assume that the number of posts in main page is 7
then `$(".post:eq(0),.post:eq(6)").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");`